# iOS13's Combine streams don't flow after operator using schedulers

Tags: swift, ios13, combine

iOS13's Combine streams of publishers don't appear to be flowing after operator using schedulers.

Here's my code:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

struct MyPublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Int
    typealias Failure = Error

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber,
        Failure == S.Failure,
        Output == S.Input {
            subscriber.receive(1)
            print("called 1")
            subscriber.receive(2)
            print("called 2")
            subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
            print("called finish")
    }
}

MyPublisher()
//    .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // If this line removed, it will be fine.
//    .throttle(for: .milliseconds(1000), scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: false)) // If this line removed, it will be fine.
//    .debounce(for: .milliseconds(1000), scheduler: RunLoop.main)) // If this line removed, it will be fine.
//    .delay(for: .milliseconds(1000), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)) // If this line removed, it will be fine.
    .print()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("finished")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }, receiveValue: { num in
        print("\(num)")
    })
```

I expected output to be

```
1
2
finished
```

but the actual output is nothing.

If I don't use `receive` or `throttle` or `debounce` or `delay`. The output will be fine.

Is it a bug or something wrong with my code?

I tried with Playground (Xcode 11 beta3).

Answer (score 4):

**Subscription:**

I'm unsure of why it works in the case of a single thread but you should make sure to call `received(subscription:)` on the `subscriber`. If you do not need to handle the subscribers demands you can use `Subscribers.empty`:

```
struct MyPublisher: Publisher {

    typealias Output = Int
    typealias Failure = Never

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
        subscriber.receive(subscription: Subscriptions.empty)
        _ = subscriber.receive(1)
        Swift.print("called 1")
        _ = subscriber.receive(2)
        Swift.print("called 2")
        _ = subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
        Swift.print("called finish")
    }
}
```

**AnyCancellable:**

You should notice a warning:

> Result of call to 'sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:)' is unused

That should appear since [`sink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3343978-sink) returns an `AnyCancellable`:

```
func sink(receiveCompletion: @escaping ((Subscribers.Completion<Self.Failure>) -> Void), receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable
```

Anything that returns an `AnyCancellable` will get canceled as soon as the `AnyCancellable` is deallocated.

My speculation is that if you are putting this on another thread, then when the end of the calling method is reached the cancellable will deallocate before the subscription is received. But when received on the current thread it seems to be executing just in time for the subscription and output to show. Most likely the cancellable is being deallocated when the current thread exits.

Comment: Sorry, my example was inappropriate. I also think cancellable handling is required.

However, it doesn't seems to work in the code handling Cancellable.

```
let cancellable: AnyCancellable

cancellable = MyPublisher()
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main) // work if it is removed
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("finished")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }, receiveValue: { num in
        print("\(num)")
    })
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5)
```

Comment: I also tried in GUI application, but the situation is same: https://github.com/kumamotone/EasyImageDownloader

I tried in Xcode11 beta4.

Comment: I think you need to call `receive(subscription:)` on the `subscriber`.

Comment: Updated my answer with info.

Answer (score 4):

**Use Cancellable**

For example :

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

func fetchImages() {
        guard let urlString  = urlString,
            let url =  URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the underscore

You can pass the underscore to pass the warning. I've used the example from Naishta's answer.

#### For example

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    

    func fetchImages() {
        guard let urlString  = urlString,
            let url =  URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        _ = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
}
```